# Properties of polynomial time many-one reductions

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions, polynomial-time

I'm working on old multiple choice exams and would like to know if the following statements are true or false:

a) $L_1 \le_p L_2 \le_p L_3 \Rightarrow L_1 \le_p L_3$

b) If $L \in \mathsf{NP}$ and $U \le_p L$ holds for all languages $U \in \mathsf{PSPACE}$ then $\mathsf{NP} = \mathsf{PSPACE}$

c) $L \in P \Leftrightarrow L \le_p \{a\}^*$

Statement a) was part of the lecture, Statesments b) and c): I don't know.

Comment: Statement a): remove it, if you know **why** it is true (what you gave is not a reason only another formulation) c: Do you have any clue, why both $\le_p$ and $\mathsf{P}$ have a p in their name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Article (a) is badly written. Writing $L_1\le_p L_2\le_p L_3$ already implies, in a way, that we have transitivity. How do you think could a reduction function for $L_1\le_p  L_3$ look like, if we know reduction functions for $L_1\le_p L_2$ and $L_2\le_p L_3$?

As for (b): If $U\le_p L$ for every language $U\in PSPACE$, then in particular this is true for some PSPACE complete language. For example, TQBF. Do you see what to do from here? (comment if not)

For (c): Also badly written, since the alphabet isn't stated, and it may affect the answer. Assuming the alphabet is not $\{a\}$, but something bigger (e.g. $\{a,b\}$), then the answer is yes: first, obviously if $L\le_p \{a\}^*$ then $L\in P$ (do you see why this is obvious?)

Conversely, if $L\in P$ then you can solve $L$ "within" a polynomial-time reduction. That is, given an input for $L$, a reduction can decide whether it is in $L$, and use the result to decide what to output.

Now, if the alphabet has other letters than $a$, then $a^*\neq \Sigma^*$, and the reduction can output something that is either in $\{a\}^*$ or not in $\{a\}^*$, depending on the input.

If, however, the alphabet is $\{a\}$, then there is no such reduction unless $L=\{a\}^*$.

Comment: I changed the transitivity part in both question and answer, as the fact that they have proven transitivity in the OP's lecture is useless for others.

Comment: Ok. So b) must be a true statements. Am I right? c) is not clear to me - unfortunately I don't see the "do you see why this is obvious?" - part and could you please summarize the true/false-cases (i undestoood that for bigger alphabets than $\{ a \}$ the statement is true). Thanks in advance!

Comment: b is true, indeed. And c is also true, unless the alphabet is a singleton. In the case of a singleton alphabet, consider what the reduction should do if it is given an input that is not in $L$. It must then output something that is not in $\{a\}^*$, but such an output does not exist. So there is a problem with the reduction.